# Precisely defining complex vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

So I was studying complex vector spaces and I think there is a problem in the way the textbook I follow defines the vector space, for example, they define the vector space,$\mathbb{V}$ saying
$$(1), \forall \left|a\right>,\left|b\right> \in \mathbb{V} \Rightarrow \left|a\right>+\left|b\right>\in \mathbb{V}$$
$$(2), \forall \left| a\right>,\left| b\right>,\left| c\right>\in \mathbb{V} \quad (\left| a\right>+\left| b\right>)+\left| c\right> = \left| a\right>+(\left| b\right>+\left| c\right>)$$
$$(3) \forall \left| a\right>\in\mathbb{V\quad}\exists \left| 0\right>\in\mathbb{V}:\left| 0\right>+\left| a\right>=\left| a\right>$$
$$(4)\forall \left| a\right>\in\mathbb{V}\quad \exists \left| -a\right>\in\mathbb{V}:\left| -a\right>+\left| a\right>=\left| 0\right>$$
$$(5) \forall\left| a\right>,\left| b\right> \in \mathbb{V},\left| a\right>+\left| b\right>=\left| b\right>+\left| a\right>$$
They also define another set of four rules defining how the elements behave with complex numbers. The rules are as follows
$$(1)\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{C}\quad \& \quad\left| a\right>\in\mathbb{V}, \alpha\left| a\right>\in \mathbb{V} $$
$$(2)\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{C}\quad\&\quad\left| a\right>,\left| b\right>\in\mathbb{V}\quad\alpha(\left| a\right>+\left| b\right>)=\alpha\left| a\right>+\alpha\left| b\right>$$
$$(3)\forall c,d\in\mathbb{C}\quad \& \quad\left| a\right>\in\mathbb{V\quad}(c+d)\left| a\right>=c\left| a\right>+d\left| a\right>$$

Now, since the only operation that the elements of $\mathbb{V}$ define amongst themselves are addition, hence I can define a set$\left\{M4\right\}$ as the set of all 4X4 matrices and pick an element from that set as$\left| a\right>$ and define another set$\left\{V3\right\}$ as the set of all 3X1 matrices/columns and pick my element $\left| b\right>$ from there. Here in $\left| a\right>,\left| b\right>\in\mathbb{V}\quad \text{but}\quad \left| a\right>+\left| b\right>\notin\mathbb{V}\quad \text{also}\quad \alpha\left| a\right>+\beta\left| b\right>\notin\mathbb{V}$. Shouldn't the definition be more restrictive. I know I sound extremely stupid, but there should be certain definitional restrictions I guess. Plus, I'm sorry if I sound naive, but, I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: What is your set $V$ in this case?

Comment: $M_4$ and $V_3$ are different vector spaces, and addition between elements of different vector spaces need not be defined (but notice that if you add any 4x4 matrices you still get a 4x4 matrices, so $M_4$ for example satisfies axiom). Otherwise, I think only problem with your given axiom is that it does not say multiplication with scalars are associative.

Comment: It says, given a quadruple$(\mathbb{V},\mathbb{C,+,.})$, where $\mathbb{V}$ is a set of objects usually calle dvectors, $\mathbb{C}$ is complex no., + is addition and'.' is multiplication among elements of $\mathbb{V} \text{and} \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @user160738 How do you say $M_4$ and $V_3$ are different vector spaces??

Comment: @user160738: I mean, is dimensionality restricted while defining a vector space??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by dimensionality. You are saying as if you are treating a set $M_4\cup V_3$ is a vector space, but it is NOT precisely because as you noted addition is not even defined. But instead $M_4$ and $V_3$ themselves are vector spaces in their own right. Just consider two elements (4x4 matries) in $M_4$ and check that axioms are satisfied: if $A,B$ are in $M_4$ you can see that $A+B$ is in $M_4$ (component-wise addition) and for any complex scalar $\alpha A$ (component wise multiplication) is also in $M_4$ (matrix is over $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but: (i) Axiom 3 should read "There exists $0$ such that for all $a$ in $V$..." (there is only one zero vector, not a zero vector for each vector); (ii) The customary (and crucial) axioms $c(da) = (cd)a$ for all scalars $c$ and $d$, all vectors $a$, and $1a = a$ for all $a$ in $V$ are omitted.

Answer (score 1):

As you say in your comment, vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is, by definition, a quadruple $\{\mathbb{V},\mathbb{C},+,\cdot\}$, where $\mathbb{V}$ is a set whose elements are the **vectors**. So if $\mathbb{V}=\{M4\}$ we have a vector space that is different from the vector space that we have with $\mathbb{V}=\{V3\}$.

In other words if the vectors are $4\times 4$ matrices, they cannot be $3\times 1$ matrices.